# Delvering a modified database from the local env to the production one

Tags: mysql

I'm working with MySQL databases.
To simplify the problem, let's say I have two environments : the local one (development) and the remote one (production mode).

In the database, I have some tables that contain configuration data.

How can I automate cleanly the delivery from the development mode to the production mode when I modify the database schema and the configuration tables content ?

For instance, I dot it manually by doing a diff between the local and remote databases. But, I find that method not so clean and I believe there is good practice allowing that.

Comment: I could not give the bounty "manually" because there was no accurate answer to my specific needs. However, the suggestions are very good. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be helpful in cases where you have multiple environments and multiple developers making schema changes very often and using php.. https://github.com/davejkiger/mysql-php-migrations

Comment: Yes. Works decently well for us. All the schema changes are stored in particular format readable by the migrate script and once the script is run it backsup the db and applies the changes. It has some decent options to support varying dev environments.. say for example each environment can store the scripts in different paths and you can specify a path parameter when running migrate script.

Answer (score 2):

- Introduce parameter "version" for your database. This version should be written somewhere in your code and somewhere in your database. Your code will work with database only if they have equal versions
- Create a wrapper around your MySQL connection. This wrapper should check versions and if versions are not compatible, it should start upgrade.
- "Upgrade" is a process of sequential applying the list of *.sql files with SQL commands, which will move your database from one state to another. It can be schema changes or data manipulation commands.
- When you do something with database, do it only through adding new *.sql file and incrementing version.
- As a result, when you deploy your database from development enviroment to production, your database will be upgraded automatically in the same way as it was upgraded during development.

Answer (score 1):

In most of my projects I use sqlalchemy(a Python tool to manage db plus an ORM). If you have some experience(little more than beginner) with Python I highly recommend using it.
You can check [this](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/) tool with a little help of [that](http://caneypuggies.alwaysreformed.com/wiki/DevelopingWithMigrations). This is also very useful for migrating your db to other rdbms(for example mysql to postgres or oracle).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen LiquiBase http://www.liquibase.org/ a lot in Java environments.